# Ada support for variables in put_line's?

Tags: objective-c, ada

Does Ada have support for something similar to an Obj-C variable in a string?

`NSLog(@"This is text, here's a variable %f", floatvar);`

I'd like to be writing nice one-liners, like:
`put_line("The answer is %v", answer);`

instead of

`put_line("The answer is ");

 put(answer);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `F : Float;`, you can say

```
Put_Line (“the answer is “ & Float’Image (F));
```

This doesn’t work so well if you want neat formatting, because the format output by `’Image` is fixed [as specified in the ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5.html#I1584) (that link’s actually to `’Wide_Wide_Image`, not `’Image`, but the format’s the same).

If you’re using GNAT, you could write the above as

```
Put_Line (“the answer is “ & F'Img);
```

which saves (a) characters and (b) remembering the type concerned, but that’s not portable.

Comment: While I was fond of both answers, this one was simpler and worked for my tests.

My professor, on the other hand, disagreed whether this was the worth the effort but for the sake of my curiosity, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You might like the Ada FAQ, specifically [part 9.9](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/computer-lang/Ada/programming/part4/). For completeness, I quote it here:

> While the standard package Text_IO provides many features, the
>   request for a printf-like function is not unusual.
>
> (solution based on a suggestion by Tucker Taft)
>
> It is possible to produce a printf-like capability by overloading
>   the    "&" operator to take an object of type Format and an object of
>   some    type and return the Format, properly advanced, after having
>   performed    the appropriate output. The remaining format can be
>   converted back to    a string--e.g. to examine what is left at the end
>   of the format    string-- or simply printed to display whatever
>   remains at the end. For    example:
>
> ```
>  with Text_IO;
>  package Formatted_Output is
>    type Format is
>      limited private;
>
>    function Fmt (Str : String)
>      return Format;
>
>    function "&" (Left : Format; Right : Integer)
>      return Format;
>    function "&" (Left : Format; Right : Float)
>      return Format;
>    function "&" (Left : Format; Right : String)
>      return Format;
>    ... -- other overloadings of "&"
>
>    procedure Print (Fmt : Format);
>
>    function To_String (Fmt : Format)
>      return String;
>
>  private
>    ...
>  end Formatted_Output;
>
>  with Formatted_Output; use Formatted_Output;
>  procedure Test is
>    X, Y : Float;
>  begin
>    Print (Fmt("%d * %d = %d\n") & X & Y & X*Y);
>  end Test;
> ```
>
> The private part and body of Formatted_Output are left as an
>   exercise    for the reader ;-).
>
> A "File : File_Type" parameter could be added to an overloading of
>   Fmt    if desired (to create something analogous to fprintf).
>
> This capability is analogous to that provided by the "<<" stream
>   operator of C++.